# OAuth2 - get authorities in resource server for a client_credential grant type

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to use the client-credential authentication type but I'm stuck, when I want to decode the JWT token in my resource server, impossible to access to the authority that I set in my authentication server...
In my authentication server I have something like this:

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("mkt-cms")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds)
                .and()
                .withClient("myClientA")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENTA")
                .scopes("read")
                .secret("mySecret")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds);
    }
```

And in my authorization server I have:

```
 @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/products").hasRole(""ADMIN")

                .antMatchers("/**/submissions/pending-approval").access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('CLIENTA')")
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

I'm using JWT tokens.

**In the first case (working case - authentication type = password):**

When the app is on the behalf of a user, it's fine I have a token decoded like this:

```
{"alg":"HS256"}{"user_name":"emil.brigand","scope":
    ["read","write","trust"],"exp":1426344414,"authorities":
    ["ROLE_ADMIN"],
    "jti":"5f03d88f-d5bc-497d-b2f3-054cb6389407","client_id":"mkt-cms","username":"emil.brigand"}W.d0Þ.Óy®wÊ_Ì¸ÃR%¬ç
```

Where the role is set by the UserDetailsService (define in the provider) in my authentication server.

the Authentication object I ve got is ok, the role is set:

```
    org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
@a02f59a4: Principal: emil.brigand; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated:
 true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
```

So the URLS like `"/**/products"` are accessible by the user.

**In the second case (not working case - authentication type = cleint_credentials):**

When the app get a token, the token decoded is like this:

```
{"alg":"HS256"}{"scope":["read"],"exp":1426345300,"authorities":
    [{"authority":"ROLE_CLIENTA"}],"jti":"2b16b2fb-67ea-4068-a96a-
    7d8314fa0cde","client_id":"myClientA"}vÊ»w¤qØ:LÉ¯@½'ö$'11è
```

I don't have any authentication provider, so I son't have a userDetailsService to set a role, the only thing I have is the authority set in the authentication server with this line: `.authorities("ROLE_CLIENTA")`
And I want to be able add a rule on it in my resource server when I'm doing something like this:

```
.antMatchers("/**/submissions/pending-
approval").access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('CLIENTA')")
```

I tried :  `.antMatchers("/**/submissions/pending-approval").hasAuthority("CLIENTA")`
But not working as well...

the Authentication object I ve got is like this:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@75ae9843:
     Principal: myClientA; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: 
    remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, tokenValue=<TOKEN>; Not granted any authorities
```

EDIT:

I found that when the token is extracted and the OAuth2Authentication object is set, the authorities is ignored (set to null), we can see that in the Spring class: DefaultAccessTokenConverter.extractAuthentication, the third parameter of the OAuth2Request constructor is null and it should be the authorities... I don't understand why this behavior...

Comment: My JWT tokens contain authorities, e.g. `{"scope":["read","write"],"exp":1426310479,"authorities":["ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT","ROLE_CLIENT"],"jti":"6e159cbe-e919-4d45-b78d-8b69efd4806b","client_id":"my-client-with-secret"}` but the format is a bit different than yours. Do you have a custom `AccessTokenConverter`?

Comment: Wow Dave Syer replied, I'm happy about that :) So, no  custom AccessTokenConverter and as you can see on the EDIT part, the authentication extraction is done in DefaultAccessTokenConverter.extractAuthentication. The problem can be resumed in one line, when I'm in client_credential flow, even if I set an authority, I can't retrieve it in my Authentication object. In the token it's set like this: '"authorities": [{"authority":"ROLE_CLIENTA"}]' for a client_credential flow and set like this '"authorities": ["ROLE_ADMIN"]' for a password flow.

Comment: And the Authentication object is different, for password flow I get a  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and for client_credential flow it's an OAuth2Authentication built without authorities, why?

Comment: Re the authorities format: I'm not seeing that with the code in master. Can you try a snapshot please? Re the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` I'm not sure what you mean, I thought we were talking about JSON.

Comment: OK, I get the last bit now: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/431

Comment: And something for me is really confusing, it's the authorities set in the auth server and authorities set in userDetailsService. Because for a password flow, I can set an authority named ROLE_FOO in my authentication server and override it by a role named ROLE_BAR in case where I have a auth provider declared and set with a CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl. (I just have to return a UserDetails set with ROLE_BAR from UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername). So somehow we are loosing the ROLE_FOO set in the auth server

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. Can you ask another question? Or put it in github.